# php How to check existed before insert data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table
(id, location, timestamp, type, value)

location / timestamp / type can duplicate, 
but location + timestamp + type is unique

---

1, "Paris", 1474986000, "a", "100" 
2, "London", 1474986000, "a", "90" 
3, "Paris", 1474986000, "b", "12" 
4, "London", 1474986000, "b", "13" 
5, "Paris", 1474990000, "a", "100" 
6, "London", 1474990000, "a", "100" 
7, "Paris", 1474990000, "a", "100" 
8, "London", 1474990000, "a", "100"

---

I tried to check existed before insert using select statement, but i have >100000 record, it spend a lot of time for checking

any other solution can solve this problem? thanks~

Comment: Then put an index on those fields

Comment: Or write the INSERT query and process the duplicate error as an OK

Comment: Please check this docs:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INSERT IGNORE` that keeps the script running and does not insert duplicate keys. Or you can use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY...`

Answer (score 2):

If there is a unique constraint on that combination of columns, assuming those columns are all declared NOT NULL...

You could create a unique index. That index would speed up a "search" for existing rows, with an appropriate SELECT statement.

```
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX mytable_UX1 ON mytable (location, timestamp, type)
```

But if you have a UNIQUE INDEX defined, and the goal is to just to add rows that are missing, you could use `INSERT IGNORE`

```
 INSERT IGNORE INTO mytable ( ... ) VALUES ( ... ), ( ... )
```

An attempt to insert a row that violates a unique constraint will not throw an error.  The IGNORE keyword causes MySQL to ignore more than just duplicate key violations, it turns other errors into warnings.

> If you use the `IGNORE` keyword, errors that occur while executing the `INSERT` statement are ignored. For example, without `IGNORE`, a row that duplicates an existing `UNIQUE` index or `PRIMARY KEY` value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With `IGNORE`, the row is discarded and no error occurs. Ignored errors may generate warnings instead, although duplicate-key errors do not.

Another technique I have used is to perform a check within the INSERT itself, using an `INSERT ... SELECT ...` with the SELECT statement including an anti-join to eliminate rows that already exist. This approach only checks for rows that already exist in the table, not "duplicates" that might be produced by the SELECT statement.